# Serialization throws Exception WriteAbortedException Class is not serializable

Tags: java, serialization, nested-object

Everytime I try to compile my code I get the Error, that my class "Score" is not serializable:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted;
java.io.NotSerializableException: Score
```

I try to serialize an object which contains mostly primitive Datatypes except for one attribute which is an object of the same class again.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Score implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String studienElement;
  private String subject;
  private float score;
  private int attempts;
  private int[] weight;
  private Score subScore;
```

I am not really sure if that is the problem. When I serialize, I try to serialize a HashMap which is built like this

```
HashMap<String, Score>
```

Appareantly the problem should be somewhere in Score.

The writing process is in this piece of code

```
public static void writeSyllabus(HashMap<String, Score> syllabusMap){
    File syllabusFile = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try{
      syllabusFile = new File(syllabusPath);
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(syllabusFile)));
      oos.writeObject(syllabusMap);
    }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      if(oos != null){
        try{
          oos.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Score
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1460)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1160)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2216)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at DataHandler.getSyllabus(DataHandler.java:97)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Score
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1840)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1411)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at DataHandler.writeSyllabus(DataHandler.java:33)
    at Syllabus.createSyllabus(Syllabus.java:183)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:23)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:12)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I added the full stack trace

Comment: The same seems to work for me. This error occurs when the class has not implemented Serializable. Are you sure you have compiled the file properly?

Comment: It would be usefull to see the whole Tester.main code. Do you initialize everything poperly? Ant what is at DataHandler.writeSyllabus(DataHandler.java:33) line 33?

Comment: @piradian you pointed out the correct thing, I never set up the routine correctly. Thanks for giving me the correct bump. It actually works now